# format php output in html table

Tags: php, html

I have a following code which I have written to convert the download monitor output to html table.

```
<div class="table-1">
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Lab Title</th>
<th>Download</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php $dlm_download->the_title(); ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php $dlm_download->get_the_download_link(); ?>">
    <?php $dlm_download->the_title(); ?> (<?php echo $dlm_download->get_the_download_count(); ?>)</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

however this gives me the output as shown below

[image]

how can I modify code so the table headers aren't repeated for every download.

Update: here's the php code

```
<?php global $dlm_page_addon; ?>
<div class="download_category download_group">
    <!-- <h3><a href="<?php // echo $dlm_page_addon->get_category_link( $category ); ?>"><?php //echo $category->name; ?> <?php //if ( $category->count ) : ?>(<?php //echo $category->count; ?>)<?php //endif; ?></a></h3> -->

            <?php while ( $downloads->have_posts() ) : $downloads->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $dlm_download = new DLM_Download( get_the_ID() ); ?>
            <?php $template_handler = new DLM_Template_Handler(); $template_handler->get_template_part( 'content-download', $format, $dlm_page_addon->plugin_path() . 'templates/', array( 'dlm_download' => $dlm_download ) ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

As far as I understand, this code passes the array $dlm_download to the template. The template code is the one with the table and has repeating table headers. I want to have a three column table with download title, category and download link.

Comment: did you have any `php` loop code around this code?

Comment: You're not showing any PHP code, so it's impossible to say anything. But Anant's assumption is most likely correct: you're looping and outputting all this every time. Put only the part that needs to be repeated inside the loop.

Comment: added the loop code.

Comment: Added picture. Rest of the question seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<th></th>` tags with `<td></td>` and use `<strong>Content</strong>`

```
<div class="table-1">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Lab Title</strong></td>
            <td>Download</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php $dlm_download->the_title(); ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php $dlm_download->get_the_download_link(); ?>">
                    <?php $dlm_download->the_title(); ?> (<?php echo $dlm_download->get_the_download_count(); ?>)</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why on Earth would one break the semantic formatting with `th` and `td`? They exist for a reason. And this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: you are right @SamiKuhmonen  . This is no where answer of the question

Comment: I am not from php background but I can make out from the answer that it won't help me